# How to transfer one ListModel into an other one in Java

Tags: java, list, listmodel

I have two ListModels: listModelRight und listModelLeft. I just want, that listModelRight = ListModelLeft, but even this dont work. How can i do it?

Code Example:

```
listModelFilterleft = listModelFilterright;
jList10.setModel(listModelFilterleft);
listModelFilterright.clear();
jList11.setModel(listModelFilterright);
```

For more Information why:
I trying to make a Filter, consisting out of two JLists and 5 Buttons. The Buttons are to put the Filtervariables from the left to the right or back again. 5 Buttons mean:

```
> from left to right
>> all from left to right
<> change left and right
<< all from right to left
< from right to left
```

If you click on >> or << all Items should go from the on list to the other list. Because of this, i will use the original Inputitems (in the correct order), which i used to fill the list with items...

Comment: Ok. I have two JList (10 and 11). The Lists are for choosing variables. In the left List are all possible to choose, in the right List are the selected. By click on Button, the Items from the right List should "go" into the left List and right List has to clear. But booth Lists are clear at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listModelFilterleft = listModelFilterright;
```

So now, these two variables reference the same, unique object.

```
List10.setModel(listModelFilterleft);
```

The first list uses that unique object as its model

```
listModelFilterright.clear();
```

And now, there is nothing anymore in this model

```
jList11.setModel(listModelFilterright);
```

And now the second list uses that same, unique, empty object as its model.

You need two discinct models. You want to remove all elements from the first one, and add them to the second one.

Comment: Ok, that means, if i clear the Filterright in line 3, also Filterleft in line 1 is clear? How can i copie the content? Did i really read all Elements from the Modellist and addElement into the other one? And last, i clear? Short: By using addElement, removeElement, clear() and loops?

Comment: Yes, you should removeElement from the first one, and addElement to the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:
It works, if u want to have: `ListModel2 = ListModel1;`
Just write: `ListModel2 =  setListModel1ToListModel2ByOverrideListModel2 (listModel1, listModel2);`

```
public DefaultListModel setListModel1ToListModel2ByOverrideListModel2 (DefaultListModel listModel1, DefaultListModel listModel2){
     listModel2.clear();
     for (int i = 0; i < listModel1.getSize(); i++){
         listModel2.addElement(listModel1.getElementAt(i));
     }
 return listModel2;
```

}